# Foreign key's causing exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this class called Match, which represents a match between two teams, however when I run the code I get an Exception.

Code:

```
[Table("Matches")]
public class Match {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public int TeamAId { get; set; }
    public int TeamBId { get; set; }

    public int TeamAScore { get; private set; }
    public int TeamBScore { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamAId")]
    public virtual Team TeamA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamBId")]
    public virtual Team TeamB { get; set; }

    public Boolean Draw {
        get { ... }
    }

    public Team Loser {
        get { ... }
    }

    public Team Winner {
        get { ... }
    }
```

}

Exception:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Matches_dbo.Teams_TeamBId' on table 'Matches' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Is there any way around this, or any change to my code I can apply to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that EF defaults to creating FK constraints with ON DELETE CASCADE. That is when a Team gets deleted, all of it's matches get deleted automatically. However, because a match points to multiple teams, that would create a circular deletion loop where deleting the match would require the deletion of the other team, which would require deleting it's matches, and so on.

To fix this, use the fluent configuration to set up your associations so that you can manually turn off ON DELETE CASCADE. For example:

```
class MatchConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Match> {
    public MatchConfiguration() {
        this.HasRequired(m => m.TeamB)
            .WithMany(t => t.Matches) // if you don't have the property Team.Matches, you can pass no arguments here
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.TeamBId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

// in OnModelCreating in your db context:
builder.Configurations.Add(new MatchConfiguration);
```

There may also be a way to specify this only using attribute configurations, but I don't know of it.